# Can I create an application which monitors a user's activity on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I wish to create an application which me and my friends would subscribe to and which in turn can monitor a count of items in the news feed using the required permissions (kind of a social network statistics).

I read the developer documentation, but I couldn't find out if it's possible. Subscribing to my application (and allowing the permissions) is a one-time process for my friends. From then on, can my application read the fields mentioned in [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) for the subscribed users at any time (without the user's involvement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in using the [Real-Time Updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) from Facebook. Using this, you will no longer have to continuously "poll" the Graph API. Rather, Facebook will send the updates to your server.

Here are some sample implementations of the API, https://github.com/facebook/real-time/tree/master/samples.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Facebook used to have the "offline_access" permission which would let applications have an access token that does not expire.

Not a while ago though Facebook deprecated this permission as stated in *[Removal of offline_access permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)*.

The longest (that I'm aware of) that a token is valid for is 60 days. If you want to extend that time frame you'll have to get the user to interact with your application.

Comment: Will this 60 day token work for all permissions(including extended ones)? So is it possible to automate the news feeds counting process via an app(once my friends approve this app) till the token is alive?

Comment: The access token you get is the result of the user being authenticated and authorizing your app, when you send him for this process you ask for a list of permissions (if any), the user then grant you these permissions (or part of them) and you get the token along with the expiration date. Till then, that access token is valid for all the permissions the user granted your app. Authentication doc: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/